# How to add to border to area range in Highcharts(areachart)

Tags: graph, highcharts, range, axis

http://jsfiddle.net/7gvuA/30/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/7gvuA/30/)

[adding a border to area range in area chart(Highcharts)](http://jsfiddle.net/7gvuA/30/)

[image: Line to area chart for the first series]

```
How to add a line to start and end of the first series in Highcharts.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50568082/how-to-add-to-border-to-area-range-in-highchartsareachart

How to add border-area-range-in-highchart(areachart)

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be achieved via chart options but this simple custom code does the job:

```
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var borderSeries = this.series[2];
      borderSeries.area.attr({ // borderSeries.area is SVGElement
        stroke: 'red',
        'stroke-width': 5,
        d: borderSeries.area.d + ' Z' // close the area
      });
    }
  }
```

It changes SVG of the area series directly.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/edw44ux4/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr